# Java inheritance -- type subclasses

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is more sort of how to design the concept

1. Post class which should work as base class having all the common attributes - concrete class
2. Question and Answer extends Post class. They have all the attributes of Post plus attributes specific to them.
3. There can be different type of Questions like UserAskedQuestion or BookQuestion - which again extends Question (concrete class) ---- here 3 level of inheritance (UserAskedQuestion -> Question -> Post)

   Here is what I want to achieve : 
   All these entities are stored in database and I want to fetch from there ( it can be cassandra or Mysql)  so idea is that,  user's one line intro will be saved as a post, where as, if user asks the question, it will be stored as a userAskedQuestion. But now if I want to know all the post posted by that user, its should include both post( one liner ) as well as (question asked)

Questions :

1. Is it good to have 3 level of inheritance ? Since I have read a lot that inheritance will complicate the code but at this point I am not able to find any other solution.
2. How should i attempt to implement it so that If I fetch Post, it should fetch all post, question/answer and their subtypes, If I fetch Question, it should fetch all question and question subtypes ?
3. If not inheritance, is there any other way to achieve this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Define "fetch". From where do you want to "fetch"? A file, a database, a list in memory?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Questions 1**

Yes of course multilevel inheritance will give you better design. I think rather then complicating things it will provide you more high cohesion and less coupling.
With this design you are achieving "Information Expert" pattern from GRAPS.

**Questions 2**

See the Example [Multilevel inheritance in java with example](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/multilevel-inheritance-in-java-with-example/)

---

**Answer for question in comment:**  After getting object from DB as `Post` class you can use `instanceof` operator of java [Java Doc: The Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
public void doSomething(Post param) {
  if( param instanceof Question ) {
    System.out.println("param is a Question ");
  }
  else if( param instanceof Answer) {
    System.out.println("param is an Answer");
  }
 // Even you can check for whether its UserAskedQuestion or BookQuestion also
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sumit, This gives me better structure but complication starts when I want to fetch all posts by user from db, there I want to fetch post object and it objects of all its derived classes. Either I have to add type in the post class, to indicate the type of the post but it will be parent knowing what type of child there will be, so it will be coupling. Hope I am clear. I have also updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `Decorator` pattern is the way to go..

Make Post an Interface. Question and Answer as Abstract Classes which implement Post.

Comment: Thanks WhoAmI, user can directly create instance of post too, so cannot be just interface. Same as for Question/Answer.

Comment: As per my understanding, every question / answer is a Post. Are you sure making Post instantiable a good design?

Comment: Apart from whole inheritance, yes I want Post Instantiable, because as I said before, user one liner can be Post, note can be Post as Post contains most of the attributes. Such term doesnt fit in question/answer world.